# Toggle between two colors when key is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I'm currently learning `C#` with `Unity` and I created a simple game where you can change the color of the player (which is red by default) by clicking the "C" key (which will change to green).
The code works but, the problem is, I don't know how to create a code that changes the green color to red color again by using the same key ("C").
The only alternative I know is to create another `if` but with a different button.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cubecolor : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.green;

    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so the `Update` method that changes the color to green correct..? why not create a button and have it do the same thing or call the update method..? what's stopping you from doing that..?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand well what do you mean. Can you explain in other words if you don't mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to press C key to change color to red and press it again to chage to green. This is really basic programming stuff.

You need to use a boolean variable then flip or inverse it each time you press the key. The flipping is accomplished by using the `!` sign. If the boolean variable is true, use red color, else use the green color.  I do encourage you to read and understand [*logical operators*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_logical_operators.htm) and [*decision making*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_decision_making.htm) in C#. You will need those in order to make an actual game yourself.

```
Renderer yourRenderer;
bool red = true;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    yourRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    //Use red as default
    yourRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        //Flip the boolean variable to the opposite of what it is
        red = !red;

        //If true, use red color
        if (red)
        {
            yourRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
        }
        //If false, use green color
        else
        {
            yourRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Unrelated, use `GetKeyDown` instead of `GetKey` otherwise you will run into problems while changing color multiple times in a frame therefore not being able to see the color change.

Comment: It's working! Huge Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Remember it's not about working or not. It's about understanding what I wrote so that you can apply that to solve your problems in your future code. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, you're completely right! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Create an if-else structure within the `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))`:

```
 void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        {
            var myObject = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

            Color currentColor = myObject.material.color;
            if(currentColor == Color.green)
            {
               myObject.material.color = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
               myObject.material.color = Color.Green;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I would do this.

```
Private Renderer objectRenderer = gameObject.getComponent<Renderer>();
Private Update() {
    If(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        If(objectRenderer.material.color == Color.green)    
           objectRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
        else
           objectRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
}
```

Comment: It is inefficiënt to retrieve the  gameObject.getComponent<Renderer>() twice!

Comment: Yeah my bad, fixed it ^^

Comment: AFAIK, you can't retrieve the component when declaring the class attribute. You have to do this in the `Awake` / `Start` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily done by using a `bool` variable:

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using UnityEngine;

            public class cubecolor : MonoBehaviour {
                private bool isGreen = false; /*Let's create a boolean to store if the cube  
                is green or red*/


                // Use this for initialization
                void Start () {
                    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;
                }

                // Update is called once per frame
                void Update () {
                    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C){
                        if(isGreen){ //Check if the color is green
                            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;
                        }else{
                            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.green;
                        }
                        isGreen = !isGreen; //Switch the boolean.
                    }
            }
```